# What does it mean when you declare a friend and then define it inside a class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand a code snippet that I've managed to make work by trial and error.   I understand everything about this snippet except why it doesn't work when I take "friend" out of the class declaration.   I don't understand what friend is doing in this context.

```
stringstream log;
```

class logWrapper {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, logWrapper& thislogend)
        {
        stringstream &ss = dynamic_cast(os);
        // This line replaced with printf for clarity
        // The actual code sends the C style string to a
        // legacy logging system that only takes C style strings
        // _log(LOG_ERR, "%s", ss.str().c_str());
        printf("%s\n", ss.str().c_str());

ss.str("");
    return os;
    }
} logend;

int main(void)
{
log << "This is a test" << logend;
}

Comment: It means your lazy. But lazy is good in programming.

Comment: @Martin: Not just laziness... it has it's advantages too

Comment: @David Rodríguez: Yes thats why I said lazy is good. It implicitly documents the tight coupling and extension of the interface.

Comment: @Martin, it does not only *implicitly* document, but changes the lookup rules. If the `friend` is defined inside the class brackets, then it will not be available in the enclosing namespace *unless* one of the arguments is of the enclosing class type.

Comment: @David: Nice point. But also note 99.9% of the time that will be true because the purpose of friend is to give it access to members. So unless you are only accessing static members then one of the parameters will be the object that it is in closed in. Thus Koenig (or AD) lookup will be used to find the function. So your statement is technically true it is rarely  factor.

Comment: I have seen it become a factor actually in the opposite direction: declare friend in a template class, define it externally and have the template greedily matching more than the programmer originally wanted... I recommend defining friend functions of templates inside the class template as it usually reduces the amount of surprises, for example.

Answer (score 7):

You are simultaneously declaring and defining a friend function, which overloads an operator.

Functions which are declared as `friend` can access all the private members of any instance of the class which befriended them.

This is different from regular member functions (which can obviously also access private members), since friend functions *are not members of the class* -- they are stand-alone functions.

So since you've defined the stand-alone function *inside* the class, it appears confusing at first glance -- just remember that it's not really a member function at all.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the friend is not a member of the class, but you can access `static` class members and member types (including `private` ones) without qualification.

This makes the function "look and feel" like a member. Because `operator<<` here is intimately tied to the `logWrapper`, it is intuitive that you can **implement it as if it were a member** of the class.

**But remember, it is not a member!** It is just a free function with special access privileges, just as if it were defined outside.

Edit: Since there are no static members and no member types, this happens not to make a difference here. You could move the definition of the friend outside without changing it. This style is idiomatic, though, because you could. Often it is used with templates, which often do have member types/typedefs.

Indeed, defining a friend inside a `template<…> class` block is the only way to define a *templated non-template function*. This esoteric and sometimes-elusive beast is nonetheless sometimes very convenient to have around. Usually his creation is accidental, even serendipitous, so I won't get into that discussion…

Comment: This is mostly wrong, sorry. Friend has nothing to do with static

Comment: And you can access normal members via an object (in this case the second parameters `thislogend`).

Comment: @Cameron: `friend` has nothing to do with `static`, but defining inside the `class { }` scope means that other names defined within the `class { }` scope do not need to be qualified. This includes `static` members and member types.

Comment: @Martin: I never said you can't access normal members. Huh?

Comment: @David: No, it is not a part of the class. It is a free function (not a member of anything), the definition of which has special qualification rules to use class-internal names as if it were a member.

Comment: @David: It's not "part of the class"; that's the point. It's *not* a member function, but it's been defined inside the class definition as part of a friend function definition for convenience/laziness.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Good point about unqualified names, but the first part of your answer is still a little unclear, and in my opinion a little misleading (while still technically true).

Comment: @Cameron: misleading about what?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You've edited it (to include member types and that they can be private), so it's perfectly fine now. +1 ;-)

Comment: just wanted to sound clever i think

Answer (score 3):

Besides what has been written before, the lookup rules are slightly different. If the `friend` function is declared *and* defined inside the befriending type, then it will only be considered if one of the arguments is of that particular type:

```
struct A {};
struct B {
   B() {}                        // allow default construction
   B( A const & ) {}             // and implicit conversion from A
   friend void foo( B const & )  // defined in the class
   {}
   friend void bar( B const & );
};
void bar( B const & ) {}         // defined outside
int main() {
   A a;
   bar( a );                     // ok, implicit conversion and calls bar(B(a))
   //foo( a );                   // error: foo not in scope!!! [*]
   B b;
   foo( b );                     // ok: the argument makes the compiler look inside B
   foo( B(a) );                  //     same here
}
```

[*] Since `foo` is *defined* inside `B`'s braces, lookup will not find `foo` unless the argument (at least one argument) is of type `B`, and that will inhibit the implicit conversion from `A` to `B` --since the potential overload is not found, conversion is not performed.

This is one of the reasons why, when defining a template, it is better to provide the implementation of the `friend` functions (specially operators) inline, as that reduces the scope of the functions and reduces namespace pollution.

Answer (score 1):

Normally `friend` just tells the compiler, that the `operator<<` has access to the private variables of `logWrapper`. In your case it's used to directly implement the `operator<<` inside the `logWrapper`. Could've also been implemented like this:

```
class logWrapper{
}logend;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, logWrapper& thislogend){
  // ...
}
```

If you didn't use `friend`, you would declare that `operator<<` as a member function of `logWrapper`. It's easier to understand with a normal function:

```
class logWrapper{
  int func(int i, logWrapper& thislogend){
    // ...
  }
}logend;
// needs to be called as:
logend.func(5,logend);
// while
class logWrapper{
  friend int func(int i, logWrapper& thislogend){
    // ...
  }
}logend;
// would be called as
func(5,logend);
```

Comment: Yes, except: (a) it is slightly different w.r.t. qualification rules inside the function's definition; and (b) you forgot the `friend` statement in your class definition example.

Comment: So if I declare a function as friend inside a class then define it, it will be defined as a global function?  So, the result of this is just prettier code then?

Comment: @Tomalak: I didn't, the OP doesn't even use any variables (if it has any) of the `logWrapper`. It's special for the use-case the OP presented in the question.

Comment: @David Hinkle: You're confusing the terms "free function" and "global function", but the idea that you have in your head is basically correct, yes. :)

Comment: @Xeo: `friend` is completely key to this question. If you're going to show an example of the friended function being defined out-of-line, I think a good example should show the resulting friend function _declaration_ left inside the class definition. Otherwise they are not even close to equivalent.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's not key to this question w.r.t. accessibility of private variables, as the code in the question doesn't even have/uses any. In the case the OP presented, it's only used to have the function where it logically belongs to.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand how this is working now, and I think I will use this idiom actually quite often when dealing with iostream.

Comment: @Xeo: It doesn't access private variables? "// The actual code sends the C style string to a legacy logging system that only takes C style strings" in the question. i.e. yes of course it does. This question is about `friend`, so let's discuss how `friend` works! Not arbitrary free functions.

Comment: @Tomalak: No it doesn't. It casts the passed `ostream` into a `stringstream` and uses the c-string of *that*. The `logWrapper` doesn't even have any members.

Comment: @Xeo: _Completely irrelevant_. It's a question about friends, so don't leave out the friends. `logWrapper` is _clearly_ stripped down for a testcase. Of course it'll have members in real life.